# why talend data transfer slow intermittently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, talend

We are suddenly experiencing slow transfer rate while transferring data from Hive database to SQL server.
This behavior is inconsistent and transfer rate drops to 1,211 rows/second on bad days.

[image: Job_statistics]

The rows highlighted with red are good days where we experience a good transfer rate.

The job layout is as below the marked component is where we experience slow transfer rate.

[image: job layout]

part -1

[image]

part-2

[image]

The staging table metrics is as below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not seeing a question?

Comment: is "why talend data transfer slow intermittently?" the question you are asking? anyway, the screenshots are hard to read..

Comment: Performance can be variable due to any number of factors. Is your process the only one that uses the target SQL Server? Is it the only one to use the network layer between Talend and SQL Server? Do backups or database maintenance process run at the same time? Is the server hosting SQL Server using the High Performance power plan, or Balanced? Is it on a virtualization host on which other guests are running? ...

Comment: Hi @DaleK I have modified the question tag.
please refer it.

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa I have  spilt the screenshots into two parts 1 and part 2.
Please refer it. Also in part 2 I have marked the component.

Comment: Very hard to debug a problem from just some screenshots. Do you see anything on sql server side? Perhaps something is blocking the insert query?